# For Loop Not Iterating Properly

Tags: python, loops, merge

I wrote a program that merges several text files together, and from there, I am trying to add dates to the first column using a for loop since there are several different dates. Using these loops though, the program doesn't seem to iterate properly.

The supporting text files have a list of times without dates; however, each text file is associated with a different date. I am merging all of the text files together into one text file for easier use, though to make it useful, I am trying to add the dates to the times, which appears in the first column of the text file.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
    import glob
    from datetime import *
    mon = [6, 7]
    dayrange1 = [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
    dayrange2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    m = 0
    d1 = 0
    d2 = 0
    newline = []



    fout = open("C:\\Users\\jessica.macleod\\Desktop\\SurmontArray1.txt", "a")
    for filename in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\jessica.macleod\\Desktop\\Surmont Noise Files\\s1-424surmontnoise2012*.txt"):
        f = open(filename)
        f.next()
        f.next()
        d1 = 0
        d2 = 0
        for months in mon:

            if m == 0:

                for days in dayrange1:

                    for line in f:
                        line += str(date(2012, mon[m], dayrange1[d1])) + " "
                        fout.write(line)
                    d1 = d1 + 1
                m = m + 1


            if m == 1:

                for days in dayrange2:

                    for line in f:
                        line += str(date(2012, mon[m], dayrange2[d2])) + " "
                        fout.write(line)
                    d2 = d2 + 1




        f.close()
    fout.close()
```

Comment: *"doesn't seem to iterate properly"*. Could you clarify that statement?

Comment: Please indent your code properly and explain what is your intended output.

Comment: The problem is that the dayrange1 won't seem to iterate. I'm not quite sure what the problem may be, since the iteration seemed to work fine before I added the if statements.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm still somewhat unfamiliar with using this site. I did indent the program properly until I put it on here. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: If `m` is `1` then both if statements will always be executed because you always increment `m` at the end of your first if statement.

Comment: @user1620716: See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for dealing with code blocks. :-)

Comment: The indentation is fixed now. Steven, I see what you mean. What would be a better way to increment m in this case?

Comment: I just elaborated my question a bit. I do hope it helps.

Comment: What is the format of the date in your filenames? Is it YYYYMMDD or something else? I think the iteration problem is because you're both looping over your files and then (inside that loop) looping over dates, when they should really be tied together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dayrange1` is not iterated over in the second loop of `for months in mon` because you have set `m` to `1`. It is skipped because it is guarded by the conditional `if m == 0:`.  This means that only the very first matched filename in your glob will have the results of iterating over `dayrange1`.  You'll need to reset `m` to `0` inside of one of your loops.

Also, you iterate over `days` in `daterange1`.  During the first iteration of that loop you iterate over the entire contents of `f`.  That means on the second iteration over `daterange1` the file is used up.

Also, you don't use `days` inside of your loop.

Comment: I tried changing it to have an if statement where if d1 == len(dayrange1): m = m + 1, but it still seems to skip over the loop.
Any ideas?

Comment: `m` become `1` for all of your loops thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can best solve your iteration issue by combining your date-loop with your filename-loop. There are two ways go do this, depending on how flexible or deterministic you want your program to be:

- If you only need the program to work for specific days that you will hard-code into the program, you should do a date loop and open the files that correspond to those days directly (with no globbing and looping over filenames).
- If instead you want the program to handle all days for which you have data files, you should drop the date loop in favor of a glob loop, and parse the filenames to get the associated dates.

Here's some untested code for the first case:

```
from datetime import date

months = [6, 7]
days = { 6 : [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
         7 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }

output_filename = "SurmontArray1.txt"
filename_template = "Surmont Noise Files\\s1-424surmontnoise2012%2d%2d.txt"

with open(output_filename, "a") as f_out:
    for month in months:
        for day in days[month]:
            with open(filename_template% (month, day)) as f_in:
                date_str = str(date(2012, month, day)) + " "
                for line in f_in:
                    f_out.write(date_str + line)
```

And here's code for the second case:

```
from datetime import date
import glob
import re

output_filename = "SurmontArray1.txt"

with open(output_filename, "a") as f_out:
    filenames = glob.glob("Surmont Noise Files\\s1-424surmontnoise2012*.txt")
    for filename in filenames:
        year, month, day = re.search(r'(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)\.txt',
                                     filename).groups()
        with open(filename) as f_in:
            for line in f_in:
                date_str = str(date(year, month, day)) + " "
                for line in f_in:
                    f_out.write(date_str + line)
```